# Can't set color to white in Snackbar - Android

Tags: android, colors

I am using https://github.com/nispok/snackbar library for Snackbar implementation. I want this snackbar to be white, so I wrote code like this :

```
SnackbarManager.show(Snackbar.with(context)
    .text(R.string.you_have_to_be_logged_in)
    .color(Color.WHITE)
    .actionLabel(R.string.log_me_in)
    .actionColorResource(R.color.lime_500)
    .actionListener(new ActionClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onActionClicked(Snackbar snackbar) {
            LogInDialog logInDialog = new LogInDialog();
            logInDialog.show(ft, "LogInDialog");
        }
    }));
```

As you can see in line 3 I set background color to white, but it doesn't change anything. The background is still dark. But, if I change background color to `.colorResource(R.color.lime_500)` the snackbar will change to this color.

I have also tried `.colorResource(R.color.white)` and `.color(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")`.

Why the snackbar cannot be white?

Comment: use colorResource(R.color.yourWhiteColor). You have to create Snackbar instance for this.

Comment: I have tried also colorResource(...), still doesn't work, but, what do you mean "create Snackbar instance for this"?

Comment: My guess it's because the text color is white too. Try changing them both.

Comment: I have set textColorResource(R.color.lime_500) and .colorResource(R.color.grey_white_1000) and it is still dark.

Comment: This only happens for #ffffff, if I set color to #fffff0 which is close to white, the snackbar background color is correct. Weird.

Comment: Smells bug report: https://github.com/nispok/snackbar/issues

Comment: @shkschneider you are probably right, I have set color to #FFFFFFFE which is basically white with 1 point difference in Blue and it works. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug and has been fixed in version [2.8.0](https://github.com/nispok/snackbar/releases/tag/v2.8.0)

The problem was that it was assumed that a color value of `-1` meant that the color was not defined and should use the default Material Design spec values. Turns out `Color.WHITE` IS `-1` thus it was ignored :P

Now, the "undefined" color value is set to `-10000`; this value should not cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(linearLayout, getResources().getString(R.string.add_number), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
snackbar.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this will change the color or snackbar to blue

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("Action", null); 
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) snack.getView();
group.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.red));
snack.show();
```